# How can I update a column in a table after a time of its creation?

Tags: mysql

I have a table of commands and I want to change the status of a command to 'expired' if this status did not change to something else in 30 min

**Update** :
I want this to happen every 30 min, I must not do anything. the database update itself and change the status of any command to 'expired' if this command was not handled in 30 min

Comment: `UPDATE key SET value = "expired" WHERE condition`, thats as much as I can give you with as much as you have given us. Voting to close as too broad, and complete lack of context.

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  Please add a tag that specifies the database you are really using.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? The syntax is not going to be the same. And without some table definition and clarity this is not currently answerable.

Answer (score 1):

Don't do that!  Instead, use a view or a computed column.

So, keep the most recent update date.  This should be easy, because you are modifying the table anyway.

Then, you can calculate expired as:

```
create view v_t as 
    select t.*,
           (case when status_update_dt < CURRENT_DATETIME - interval '30 minute'
                 then 'expired'
                 else status
            end) as new_status
    from t;
```

Of course, the date/time functions depend on the database (the above is ANSI syntax).  And, some databases support computed columns which puts the definition directly in the table.  This is really convenient, because you don't have to change the data; it just works when you query the data.

Comment: I actually need to change database; because it will be delete after a time, It like a temporary table that hundl commands of restaus

Comment: @brahimm . . . Your comment makes no sense.

Comment: ok! I need somthing in sql that updates my database in condition.

Comment: ok! I need somthing in sql that updates my tabel of commands in condition.
the condition is the commnd did not change its status in 30 min